# Separation of variables, differential equation, how to consult results for different lambdas

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve following problem

$$
    u_{tt}=u_{xx}
$$
$$
    u_x(\pi,t)=u_x(0,t)=0
$$

I've started

$$
    u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)
$$
$$
    X''(x)/X(x)=T''(t)/T(t)=\lambda
$$
when
$$
    \lambda<0 
$$
$$
    X(x)=cos(kx)
$$
$$
    \lambda=0 
$$
$$
    X(x)=B
$$
and now I've stuck, because I don't know how should I consult fact that X(x)=B.
But for that I could write:
$$
    u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^{inf} cos(kx)(C_k cos(kt) + D_k sin(kt))
$$
Could anyone help me solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a solution of form $at+b$. You could just eliminate this solution saying that you require a periodic solution (like you probably did while eliminating the case $\lambda>0$) or add it to your current sum.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've made terrible mistake should be u_x(0,t) not u(0,t)

Comment: Thank you. But could you explain in a few words why I get at+b?

Comment: Solve $$T''=0$$ and remember $u=XT=BT$.